# Activity not starts when i try to share from my application

Tags: android, android-intent, share, intentfilter

i have specified intent filters for my Activity

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and intent is as follows

```
Intent testone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        testone.setType("image/*");
                        testone.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri_new);
```

my activity not starts when i try to share from my application but it starts when i try to share a gallery image

Comment: Add **startActivity(testone);**

Answer (score 0):

First you create the intent for the new activity then you use it to start the activity
so with this

> Intent testone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>                           testone.setType("image/*");
>                           testone.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri_new);

you created the Intent, now just have to start the activity using

```
startActivity(testone);
```

you can find a complete example of share intent [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433)